# how to write an reversed words function in haskell

Tags: string, haskell, reverse

Write a program that reads a text in an endless loop, every single word
flipped over and then put back together as text. If the input is empty, the program should
abort, stop.
To do this, write a `reverseWords::String -> String` function that does the reversing
is working.

for example:

```
reverseWords "Hello World, 123" -> "olleH ,dlroW 321"
```

my code

```
reverseWords :: String -> String 
reverseWords = unwords . reverse . words
```

doesnt work

Comment: Do you have a specific question or a problem in the code you've written?

Comment: yes, i have this code reverseWords :: String -> String
reverseWords = unwords . reverse . words but it isnt working

Comment: Is the comma really supposed to be part of `World`, rather than punctuation  to be preserved in the resulting sentence? `"olleH dlroW, 321"`

Comment: @MichaelLitchard the OP have added their code attempt now (10 minutes after posting).

Comment: What's supposed to happen if there are multiple spaces between words? What if there are spacing characters other than `' '`, such as line breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `reverse` reverses the entire list, so you are getting the words in the reverse order. What you want instead, is to reverse *each element* separately, which can be fixed with `map`:

```
reverseWords = unwords . map reverse . words
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to preserve spacing characters other than `' '`, then things get a little tricky. Fortunately, the `split` package can help.

```
import Data.List.Split
import Data.Char

reverseWords :: String -> String
reverseWords = concatMap reverse . split (whenElt isSpace)
```